# Syntax Error SQL Near TEXT

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to use an SQL database for my android app however a syntax error is being logged in the form of:

```
(1) near "TEXT": syntax error
```

This comes from a create table statement which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PlacesTable (
_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT,
lat TEXT,
lon TEXT,
place TEXT,
Section TEXT,
type TEXT,
desc TEXT,
misc TEXT,
bigpic TEXT,
smallpic TEXT,
Mon TEXT,Tue TEXT,
Wed TEXT,
Thu TEXT,
Fri TEXT,
Sat TEXT,
Sun TEXT,
Addr TEXT,
Tel TEXT,
Web TEXT,
TypeOfR TEXT,
PriceR TEXT,
hasDiscount TEXT,
DiscountType TEXT,
Discount TEXT,
Kosher TEXT,
Children TEXT,
Featured TEXT,
Mall TEXT,
Unique TEXT )
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique is a reserved keyword.  You have to rename that column to UniqueVal or something like that.  That most likely is your problem.

Comment: is desc also a reserved word?

Comment: No problem.  You should take a look at the documentation for SQLite it may help you learn a few new tricks like primary/unique keys and other types that can help you.